# Signals and Slots help QT

Tags: c++, qt, signals

I have a Ui class with a function that i want to call every time i emit a signal from a class lets say test. in the ui function i need to connect my signal and slot but im trying the code from the QT docs and having no luck

signal declaration

```
signals:

void paint(int x, int y, int id);
```

signal emit

```
emit paint(x, y, id)
```

connection (`m_test` been a class object)

```
connect(&m_test,SIGNAL(paint(int,int,int)), this, SLOT(uiFunction(int,int,int)));
```

getting this error

> error: C2664: 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const QObject *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'uiFunction *' to 'const QObject *'

but i follwed this QT docs example (counter being the class)

```
Counter a, b;
     QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                      &b, SLOT(setValue(int)));
```

any ideas?

Comment: It's saying your `m_test` type does not derive from `QObject`.

Comment: ok but neither does the one in the example from QT docs

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html `a small example`

Comment: `class Counter : public QObject`...  Try again.

Comment: And don't forget Q_OBJECT macros

Comment: `void paint(int x, int y, int id);` is a terrible signal name. paint is already used by Qwidget as a slot.

Comment: good thing its not my actual names then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need your Ui class to inherit from QObject and then add the QOBJECT macro just after the declaration of the class. e.g.

```
class Ui : public QObject
{
    QOBJECT

signals:
    void paint(int x, int y, int id);

private slots:
    void UiFunction(int x, int y, int id);
};
```